# Is it possible to add a function-based database-agnostic index via a Rails/ActiveRecord migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, indexing

I have an ActiveRecord model like this:

```
create_table "books" do |t|
  t.string "title"
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'lower(title) DESC'
end
```

As you can see I want to sort by the lowercase form of the `title` attribute, but this imposes a performance hit at the database level. This hit can be remedied in different ways with different databases. For example, in PostgreSQL or Oracle you create a function-based index:

```
CREATE INDEX lowercase_book_title_index ON book (lower(title));
```

SQLite3 doesn't have function-based indexes so you have to specify a collation:

```
CREATE INDEX lowercase_book_title_index ON book (title COLLATE NOCASE);
```

I haven't looked into how you do it with MySQL but I'm sure there's a way (collations? virtual columns?).

In any event I would like to do this in proper Rails fashion with a database-agnostic migration. I can of course create a simple index like this:

```
add_index :books, :title
```

But the index this generates is case-sensitive. I realize I could write a database-dependent migration, but it's not very elegant. It's also not practical--I often find myself using SQLite3 on my development workstations and PostgreSQL in production. The available options for add_index deal with index name, uniqueness, and length. Am I overlooking a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but using SQLite in development and PostgreSQL in production causes a lot of grief. (It bites Heroku users a lot. A *lot*.) Since PostgreSQL is also free, it doesn't really make sense to develop against SQLite.

Comment: It's been surprisingly pain-free for me provided I let ActiveRecord write the SQL. This was not the case when I was developing against MySQL and then had to deploy to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: not

Long answer: not, because not all database engines support it what Rails supports, or in a very different way. If are you sure *all* database engines supports it, then file a feature request for ActiveRecord developers.

Keep in your mind: in ActiveRecord migrations, you can only do what all database engine supports, database-specific stuffs needs separated initializations from migrations.

I recommend to setup this collation from a separated rake task what runs after db:migrate. In my bigger applications I use `rake setup` where I can do this specific steps.

Answer (score 0):

I never had any problems with that kind of sorting. Basically, what you want is that the results are sorted in this way:

```
"A bad title"
"A better title"
"a good title"
"An excellent title"
```

If this is correct and you are going with mysql, you can specify a collation in your database.yml, try:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2 # or mysql for rails < 3
  host: ...
  database: ...
  username: ...
  encoding: utf8 # or whatever you are using
  collation: utf8_general_ci # or whatever fits your language and encoding
```

utf8_general_ci means "collate with utf8 in a language independent way and be case insensitive".

This should do the trick.

Comment: That's true, and thanks for your response, but I was looking for a database-_agnostic_ way of doing it. That is, just a Rails migration may create a :binary column which becomes a blob in MySQL or a bytea in PostgreSQL, I'd like to be able to specify a case-insensitive index in my Rails migration which is handled in the appropriate way across databases.

Comment: I'm looking into the same issue, did you find a solution ? does using the default_scope with 'lower' option have a significant performance impact ?